# Does Index Using a Logical Expression work for strings?

Tags: matlab

The page

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html

shows that we can use logic expressions with tables. But it works only for numeric columns but not string columns.

```
>> T = table(categorical({'M';'F';'M'}),[45;32;34],...
             {'NY';'CA';'MA'},logical([1;0;0]),...
             'VariableNames',{'Gender' 'Age' 'State' 'Vote'})

T = 

Gender    Age    State    Vote 
______    ___    _____    _____

M         45     'NY'     true 
F         32     'CA'     false
M         34     'MA'     false

>> T.State == 'CA'
Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

>> T.Age == 32

ans =

 0
 1
 0
```

Can we make it work for strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strcmp` for comparing strings in cells:

```
>> strcmp(T.State, 'CA')

ans =

  3×1 logical array

   0
   1
   0
```