# strcmp works for table created by {} but not []

Tags: matlab

This question is related to [Does Index Using a Logical Expression work for strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713051/does-index-using-a-logical-expression-work-for-strings/39713136#39713136)

I found when I created a table by [] and {}. It behaves differently. It seems strcmp works only for tables created by {}. How to do the same thing for tables created by []?

```
>> T1 = table(['MM';'FF';'MM'])

T1 = 

Var1
____

MM  
FF  
MM  

>> T2 = table({'MM';'FF';'MM'})

T2 = 

Var1
____

'MM'
'FF'
'MM'

>> strcmp(T1.Var1, 'MM')

ans =

 0
```

Since T1.Var1 is a cell array, I think the above command should return an array of values as the following does.

```
>> strcmp(T2.Var1, 'MM')

ans =

 1
 0
 1

>> size(T1.Var1)

ans =

 3     2

>> size(T2.Var1)

ans =

 3     1

>> T1.Var1 == 'MM'
Error using  == 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

>> T2.Var1 == 'MM'
Undefined operator '==' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try to avoid 2d character arrays. Whenever you can, use cell arrays instead to be free from many limitations of multidimensional character arrays. Limitations like:

```
T1 = table(['M';'F';'MM'])
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

---

Now I get back to your question: You can first convert the table `T1` to cell array and then use `strcmp`.

```
strcmp(table2cell(T1), 'MM')

ans =

     1
     0
     1
```

Comment: If 2d char arrays are limited, why does MATLAB still allow this? Is it more efficient than cell arrays of chars?

Comment: It allows, because a string is a 2d (1xN) char matrix: `str = ['a','p','p','l','e']`.

Comment: @JoeC Yes, normal arrays (matrices or multi-dimensional) are generally more efficient than cell arrays. But you can't create "jagged" arrays that way. Cell arrays are more flexible